# How to automatically refresh a Listview?

Tags: java, android, json, push-notification

I have an android listview, but I have to relance the application every time that I want to refresh the list. I have two questions, please:

1) How to refresh it automatically?

2) How to do to receive a notification when an item is added to the database?

So it just tests if an item is added, I receive a notification, when I Click on it I will be able to see the list of items.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView SubjectFullFormListView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    String HttpURL = "http://254.221.325.11/test/Subject.php";
    ListAdapter adapter ;
    List<Subject> SubjectFullFormList;
    EditText editText ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SubjectFullFormListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SubjectFullFormListView);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar1);

        new ParseJSonDataClass(this).execute();


    }

    private class ParseJSonDataClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        public Context context;
        String FinalJSonResult;

        public ParseJSonDataClass(Context context) {

            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
        }



        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            HttpServiceClass httpServiceClass = new HttpServiceClass(HttpURL);

            try {
                httpServiceClass.ExecutePostRequest();

                if (httpServiceClass.getResponseCode() == 200) {

                    FinalJSonResult = httpServiceClass.getResponse();

                    if (FinalJSonResult != null) {

                        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                        try {

                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(FinalJSonResult);
                            JSONObject jsonObject;
                            Subject subject;

                            SubjectFullFormList = new ArrayList<Subject>();

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                subject = new Subject();

                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                subject.Subject_Name = jsonObject.getString("SubjectName");

                                subject.Subject_Full_Form = jsonObject.getString("SubjectFullForm");

                                SubjectFullFormList.add(subject);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(context, httpServiceClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            SubjectFullFormListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                adapter = new ListAdapter(SubjectFullFormList, context);

                SubjectFullFormListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }

}
```

I find a solution but I don't know how and where to insert it:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

Runnable refresh = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new JSONParse().execute();  
            handler.postDelayed(this, 60 * 1000);
        }
    };

handler.postDelayed(refresh, 60 * 1000);
```

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't work for me,  I don't know how to insert this code

Answer (score 0):

-> Write a runnable thread which calls the API of the list regularly after some time and on its response change the list in the adapter and call notifydatasetchanged().

-> By using FCM you can get the solution to question 2. When an item is added in DB generate a notification from server side and send it to clients sides and by using pending intent you can show the list when user tap on the notification.

```
                (OR)
```

-> You can use the real-time DB Like Firebase DB or Realm etc. for this approach. This DB notify you when an item added to the list and you don't need threads to refresh list.